# PHP parent and sub json encode

Tags: php, json, wordpress, multidimensional-array

Hi this is my json out put

```
[{
    "sri-lanka": {
        "title": "Sri Lanka",
        "districts": {
            "colombo": {
                "title": "Colombo"
            },
            "gampaha": {
                "title": "Gampaha"
            }
        }
    },
    "australia": {
        "title": "Australia",
        "districts": {
            "victoria": {
                "title": "Victoria"
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

this is my code php wordpress 
these are the categories and sub categories

```
global $wpdb;

$querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->terms.term_id, $wpdb->terms.name, $wpdb->terms.slug, $wpdb->term_taxonomy.parent  FROM $wpdb->term_relationships RIGHT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id WHERE $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'network_locations' GROUP BY $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id";

$rows = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
$refs = array();
$list = array();

foreach($rows as $items){
    $thisref = &$refs[$items->term_id];

    $thisref[$items->slug] = array('title' =>$items->name, 'district' => '');

    if($items->parent == 0){
        $list[] = &$thisref;
    } else {
        $refs[$items->parent]['district'][] = array('district' => array('id' => $items->term_id));

    }
}

echo json_encode($list);
wp_die();
```

in json out put first array object is ok but i cannot get json out put i required can i get help for create this json

i cannot understand how to 'districts' object put under with title using these line

```
$refs[$items->parent]['district'][] = array('district' => array('id' => $items->term_id));
```

from this code

this is the orginal source i refered https://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?topic=1990.0
thanks

Comment: Nobody can guess at what you want if you don't show us and explain your problem in more detail

Comment: @charlietfl done and thanks